# role of feed dictionary command in the training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand training loop. While calculating training and test accuracy we replace `x` and `y_` by training and test sets but while printing the result for cross entropy why we feed `x` and `y_` by `batch_xs` and `batch_ys` respectively? I know that we have to assign a value to the placeholders but while calculating test accuracy `batch_xs` and `batch_ys` remain same and both are using train set values.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nPixels])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nLabels])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for j in range(nSteps):
        i = nstep % nSteps
        batch_xs = np.reshape(x_train,(nSteps,bSize,nPixels))
        batch_ys = np.reshape(y_train,(nSteps,bSize,nLabels))
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs[i], y_: batch_ys[i]})

        if j % 100 ==0:
            train_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_train,y_: y_train})
            test_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test}))
            loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs[i], y_: batch_ys[i]})
```

Comment: It is hard to help you without knowing how those variables were defined. Please post all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your training loss at the same time you do a training step (so that you do not have to make a separate call, passing your batch again later) with something like:

```
for j in range(nSteps):
    # ...
    _, train_loss = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy],
                             feed_dict={x: batch_xs[i], y_: batch_ys[i]})
```

As for why you do not need to resize your training/testing sets when calculating your accuracy, let's look at the dimensions of your data throughout your code. You start out with:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nPixels])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nLabels])
```

That means that the dimensions of `x` are `[num_samples, nPixels]` and the dimensions of `y_` are `[num_samples, nLabels]`. I assume `x_train` and `y_train` are just some subsample of this, so `[num_train, nPixels]` and `[num_train, nLabels]` respectively. Next you reshape these for your batches:

```
batch_xs = np.reshape(x_train,(nSteps,bSize,nPixels))
batch_ys = np.reshape(y_train,(nSteps,bSize,nLabels))
```

Now `batch_xs` has dimensions `[num_steps, batch_size, nPixels]` and `batch_ys` has dimensions `[num_steps, batch_size, nLabels]`. Note that the *last* dimensions, the number of features or output dimensions, hasn't changed.

Now for each iteration of your training loop, you take one element from the first dimension of these lists with `batch_xs[i]` and `batch_ys[i]`. The dimensions of these guys are now `[batch_size, nPixels]`, and `[batch_size, nLables]`, respectively. Again, the last dimension hasn't changed.

Finally you call your `accuracy` or `cross_entropy` ops on a batch or on the whole training set and TF doesn't care which it is! This is because the number of features/labels you are giving it is the same either way, and all that's changing is the number of data elements you are passing. In one case you are passing `batch_size` elements, and in the other you are passing `num_train` or `num_test` elements, but the last dimensions that specify what each sample *looks like* is the same! TF is magic and figures out how to handle the difference.

### Old answer

It looks like you are just trying to get training loss out of your loop, thus you are passing your training batch to your `cross_entropy` function. A lot of times you might evaluate this at every batch and store the results so that you can plot your training loss over time later, but sometimes this calculation takes long enough that you want to only calculate it every so often. This seems to be the case for your code.

In general, it is a good idea to look at both training *and* test (or validation) loss while your training loop runs. This is because you are better able to see the effects of overfitting, where training loss continues to decrease and testing loss levels off or begins to increase. Something like:

```
if j % 100 == 0:
    train_loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs[i], y_: batch_ys[i]})
    test_loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})
    # print or store your training and test loss
```

One of the major reasons for monitoring your testing loss is to stop your training early in the event of overfitting. You can do this by storing your best testing loss, and then comparing each new testing loss to your stored best. Each time you get a new testing loss that does not beat your best, you increment a counter, and when the counter hits a certain number (say 10 or 20), you kill the training loop and call it good. This way you catch when your training has stalled out on the *validation/testing* set, which is a better indicator of when it will no longer get better at generalizing to new data.

If you encounter a new validation loss that is better than your best, you store it and reset your counter.

Finally, it is often best to hold out two sets of data, one called the *validation* set, and one called the *testing* set. When you split it up like this, you typically use the validation set while training to look for overfitting and perform early stopping, and then you run one final test for accuracy/loss against the testing set that the network has never seen before to give you an idea of its overall generalization performance. That looks something like:

```
for epoch:
    for batch in batches:
        x = batch.x
        y = batch.y
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x, y_: y})
        if j % 100 == 0:
            train_loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: x, y_: y})
            test_loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: x_val, y_: y_val})  # note validation data
            # print or store your training and test loss
            # check for early stopping
test_loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})
# Or test accuracy or whatever you want to evaluate.
# Point is the network never saw this data until now.
```

Comment: In test loss you are replacing x and y_ ny x_test and y_test but you are not replacing it with x:batch_xs[i] and y_:batch_ys[i]?

Comment: No, you always want some data held out that the network doesn't see when training so that you can evaluate how well it is performing to new data (how well it generalizes). This is how you identify and avoid overfitting; by comparing loss on the training data with loss on the held-out testing (or validation) data.

Comment: but then how the test set will know that in which format we are feeding it to the network? I'm still confused about why we are not writing x:batch_xs[i] and y_ :batch_ys[i]. Can you please explain it further. I'm clear about the training test and validation set. but this part of code is confusing me

Comment: What do you mean in which format? Typically with TF you feed your data in batches of size `[batch_size, num_features]` or `[batch_size, height, width, depth]` or whatever. The nice thing is that the *number* of samples (that `batch_size`) can be anything any time you call your function, so you can pass it batches of 32 samples for training, and then test on 2000 without having to do any extra work as long as each *sample* has the same dimensions. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Actually I want to say that in my code while calculating loss i don't need to use feed_dic because I already used feed _dic command in training step. And secondly I want to say that while defining batch_xs and batch_ys I actually reshaped Xtrain and y_train but while calculating test accuracy why i don't replace x_train and y_train (defined in batch_xs and batch_ys) by x_test and y_test.

Comment: You have to pass feed dict every time you call something, but you can make multiple calls at once. I will update my answer. Check back in a few.